OpenCL in zig creating invalid mem objects
const input_buffer = c.clCreateBuffer(context, c.CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, array_size * @sizeOf(c.cl_int), null, &ret);
try handle_error(ret);
defer _ = c.clReleaseMemObject(input_buffer);

const output_buffer = c.clCreateBuffer(context, c.CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, array_size * @sizeOf(c.cl_int), null, &ret);
try handle_error(ret);
defer _ = c.clReleaseMemObject(output_buffer);

ret = c.clEnqueueWriteBuffer(
    command_queue,
    input_buffer,
    c.CL_TRUE,
    0,
    array_size * @sizeOf(c.cl_int),
    input_array,
    0,
    null,
    null,
);
// FIXME: input_buffer valid here
try handle_error(ret);

ret = c.clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, @sizeOf(c.cl_mem), input_buffer);
// FIXME: input_buffer invalid here
std.log.debug("{d}: {s}", .{
    ret,
    @tagName(@as(CLErrorCode, @enumFromInt(-ret))),
});
if (ret != c.CL_SUCCESS) {
    return CLError.SetKernelArgFailed;
}

ret = c.clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, @sizeOf(c.cl_mem), output_buffer);
// FIXME: output_buffer invalid
try handle_error(ret);

this is the problematic code that is creating the invalid mem objects
I am running on Nixos 24.05 with an intel i3-8145U
I have looked in the docs and this should work but it doesn't
What am I doing wrong

I don't know zig, but are you sure it's safe to make the memory buffer objects constants?

@SimonGoater it gives an error if they aren't constant as what const is saying is that the pointer is constant
